# Support different customized colors and styles

Tags: android, eclipse

Im relatively new to Android. I have built an application. And set often per code the background color. I might Change the XML parts to code as well, because I want the user to have the option to chose between a red and a green layout (like colorblind mode)

I am going to define the values in a static class and then the static class will return Color.rgb(100,200,100) or Color.rgb(50,50,150) for example, depending on the settings that I will get from the decive or also only set temporarily on the static class.

I couldn't find anything about this (maybe I used the wrong keywords). Is this the right approach? Or are there guidelines to do it different (like multiple language support)?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you want to change your view background color dynamically and programmatically?

Comment: yes the user should for example pick menu:options->Alien and most Buttons will now appear in dark blue, with White text; while if he picks menu:options->nursery  all will be in White with red text

Comment: You can call [View#setBackgroundResouce](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundResource(int)) to change the background color of your views. Finally, you may need to call [invalidate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate())

Comment: yeah know how to change the the colors etc. Im just wondering if doing this with a static class that has all valuesets stored is the way to do it.